# Why don't I show up in my boyfriends messenger list at all?

Tags: facebook

I don't show up at all in my boyfriends messenger list. Could he have purposely removed me somehow? Is there a setting that could do that? I know we are friends & I think his profile even says we are in a relationship but in his messenger contact list I'm not there.

Comment: If he deleted your messenger thread then you won't be there. If this has been going on forever or just recently?

Comment: For a long time. He never deletes his messages. Everyone else is there. All his friends that are available or online but not me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have the same issue on a few of my friends. For some reason after the switch to messenger I've had this issue. What you need to to is search your name from his messenger app and you should be able to pull up your conversation with him from his messenger app. You'll have to do this every time the app closes. It's a very annoying bug and if you'd like it to be fixed you can always [report the bug](https://www.facebook.com/help/326603310765065/)